# How to unlock iPhone 4 if original carrier doesn't provide the service?

Tags: ios, iphone, unlock

I have two iPhone 4 locked by the original carrier. I can't get the factory unlock because this carrier don't provide this service.

I try to unlock via software but I can't, because the baseband (modem firmaware) are 04.12.02 (iOS 6.0.1) and 04.11.08 (iOS 5.0.1). Is not possible that I use Gevey, for the basebands. So, I think that I need wait for other new solution or maybe Apple unlock the all generation of iPhone 4.

If you know, other solution for me, please, help me. Because right now, I have only two iPod touch.

So, is possible that Apple unlock the all generation of iPhone 4?

Comment: WHich country are you in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't unlock with Apple after you've purchased an iPhone.

In the US, the laws regarding cellphone unlocking haven't changed, but a Library of Congress exemption to the law has recently not ben renewed so you might only legally unlock if your carrier allows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the original carrier maybe can unlock all old generation of an iPhone? e.g. the iPhone 4 when the iPhone 5S is released.

Comment: The original carrier _can_ unlock any generation iPhone, but only if they actually allow you to do so.

Answer (score 4):

The carrier lock is imposed by... the carrier. I don't think Apple will ever remotely unlock devices, so you must look for other ways to do it. If your phone is from AT&T and have more than one year and the customer is in good standing, you can request the carrier unlock for the device.

Apple's software clearly consults the carrier database for IMEI to determine which devices should be carrier-locked and which have SIM slots that are baseband unlocked, but Apple doesn't actually input devices into this database (unless you consider them as an agent to the Cell companies when you buy a locked or unlocked phone from Apple and initiate service with your carrier of choice).

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually find the att unlocking site to be useful, had a present from states, and it is just locked to ATT, I personally think it's worth the money to unlock the phone on that site.

Answer (score -2):

try attiphoneunlocking.com, I have unlocked my 4s over there, took me 4 hours after sending the imei number.

Comment: What makes you think this phone is from AT&T? They are a carrier that will unlock devices once the initial contract period expires or you pay to escape your contract.